# Procedural material orientation

Tags: materials, workflow, procedural, transform-orientation

I'm new here on Blender, so I create my procedural wood material and I applied it on four separate objects. I'm wondering if there's a way do give a different orientation on each object for the same material without to create 4 copies of the same material.[image]

As you can see now they are all orientated vertical in the same direction, I would like to choose the orientation separately to follow the curve.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make the lines follow the shape with the *Object* or *Generated* outputs of the *Texture Coordinate*, instead use the *UV* output and unwrap your cylinder with the *Cylinder Projection* mode for example.

Comment: That's not actually what I want, if you imagine a bounding box on those objects it should be rotated not vertical. So I just would like to follow that rotation.

Comment: If you duplicate each object, keep them separate and don't apply the rotation, it should work the way you want no?

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the object comes from another software and I'm using Blender just for rendering so I don't have the object in the " 0 " position. I was checking if there's a possibility changing the texture space for Generated output, but seams I can't rotate it.

Comment: if you keep only one leg, the one that works, then duplicate and rotate it, you should have 4 legs that work fine, not sure what the problem is